# javascript/jQuery to post and view pdf in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript form which on submit does a POST request which generates and downloads dynamically a PDF. I would like to view this PDF in a new tab.

This is what I have so far:

```
$.post({
    type: 'GET',
    url: target_url,
    data: 'content=' + JSON.stringify(editor.getValue()),
}).done(function(data){
    w = window.open('target="_blank"');
    w.document.open();
    w.document.write(data);
    w.document.close();
});
```

The post request is successful and a new tab is opened, but filled with encoded/unreadable material. How to open the results in the browsers pdf viewer?

Comment: This entirely depends on how you're returning the file from the AJAX request. It sounds like it's base64 encoded, or you may be trying to read binary data as a string.

Comment: Instead, prepare PDF on the server and return the file link.

Comment: in that case I would like to redirect to a location with post data

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a [plugin like pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) to display your PDF in the browser.

I agree with @Abhijeet WebDev that you should provide a link to the prepared PDF and load the URL to open/download the PDF in the new tab.